# execCommand fails when changing contentEditable state on the fly in iPhone/iPad 5.1

Tags: javascript, iphone, ios, ipad, cordova

An iOS application developed using PhoneGap, shows a large HTML content to user. User can make the portion of text bold, underline..., but shouldn't add or delete existing text.

So, I set contentEditable of the div as "false" by default in HTML. Using execCommand() to format the selected text. When user selects text and click "Bold" button, I am changing contentEditable to "true" before executing execCommand() and set it back to "false" then. execCommand() makes the text bold as expected in all desktop browsers including Safari, but not in iPhone/iPad.

Your help is highly appreciated.

Sample Code: (I tested it in iOS 5.1 simulator)

```
<html>
<head>
<script>
    function bold()
    {
        var content = document.getElementById("content");
        content.contentEditable = true;
        //document.body.contentEditable = true;
        var result = document.execCommand('bold', false, null);
        content.contentEditable = false;
        //document.body.contentEditable = false;
    };
</script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="content">this is the same text used for testing...</div>
    <br><br>
    <input type="button" value="bold" onclick="javascript: bold();"/>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Saying it doesn't work in iPhone/iPad means... what does it do instead? Nothing at all?

Comment: Updated the question with more details, Thanks